# Jsoup connect doesn't work correctly when link has Turkish letters

Tags: java, jsoup, turkish

I'm using `Jsoup` to get html from web sites. I'm using

```
String url="http://www.example.com";
Document doc=Jsoup.connect(url).get();
```

this code to get html. But when I use some Turkish letters in the link like this;

```
String url="http://www.example.com/?q=Türkçe";
Document doc=Jsoup.connect(url).get();
```

Jsoup sends the request like this: `"http://www.example.com/?q=Trke"`

So I can't get the correct result. How can I solve this problem?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**Working solution**, if encoding is `UTF-8` then simply use

```
Document document = Jsoup.connect("http://www.example.com")
        .data("q", "Türkçe")
        .get();
```

with result

```
URL=http://www.example.com?q=T%C3%BCrk%C3%A7e
```

For custom encoding this can be used:

```
String encodedUrl = URLEncoder.encode("http://www.example.com/q=Türk&#231e", "ISO-8859-3");
String encodedBaseUrl = URLEncoder.encode("http://www.example.com/q=", "ISO-8859-3");
String query = encodedUrl.replace(encodedBaseUrl, "");

Document doc= Jsoup.connect("http://www.example.com")
        .data("q", query)
        .get();
```

Comment: @ErdinçÖzdemir Sorry, I messed my post, which one is working :)

Comment: Encoding is UTF-8. Still second one is the true answer.

Answer (score 2):

Unicode Characters are not allowed in URLs as per [the specification](http://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc1738.txt). We're used to see them, because browsers display them in adress bars, but they are not sent to servers.

You have to URL encode your path before passing it to `JSoup`. 
`Jsoup.connect("http://www.example.com").data("q", "Türkçe")` as proposed by MariuszS does just that

Answer (score 1):

I found this on google: http://turkishbasics.com/resources/turkish-characters-html-codes.php
Maybe u can add it like this:

```
 String url="http://www.example.com/?q=Türk&#231e";
 Document doc=Jsoup.connect(url).get();
```

Comment: Yes I tried it before. But it doesn't work. String url="http://www.example.com/?q=T&#252rk&#231e"; when I sen this. It sends as String url="http://www.example.com/?q=T";

Comment: Sorry, that was my only idea :)